# Create new view on object with long text area type in filter

Tags: list-view, filters

Here i want to create a new view on object tab. Whenever i click on create new view link and go inside. After that in filter drop down i can't find one filed **Demoview**(Long Text Area).

Here i want to show the Demoview field in that filter drop down so what can i do for that?

Please it's urgent,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to filter on **Long Text Area** fields in list views currently. You can upvote this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZEtCAAW).